# invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++

For a code like this:

```
class foo {
  protected:
    int a;
  public:
    class bar {
      public:
        int getA() {return a;}   // ERROR
    };
    foo()
      : a (p->param)
};
```

I get this error:

```
 invalid use of non-static data member 'foo::a'
```

currently the variable `a` is initialized in the constructor of `foo`.

if I make it static, then it says:

```
 error: 'int foo::a' is a static data member; it can only be initialized at its definition
```

However I want to pass a value to `a` in the constructor.
What is the solution then?

Comment: why don't you move getA() to foo?

Comment: The code in your question has several problems that make it unclear what you're really trying to do. Please edit you question to indicate what your overall goal is.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In C++, unlike (say) Java, an instance of a nested class doesn't intrinsically belong to any instance of the enclosing class. So `bar::getA` doesn't have any specific instance of `foo` whose `a` it can be returning. I'm guessing that what you want is something like:

```
    class bar {
      private:
        foo * const owner;
      public:
        bar(foo & owner) : owner(&owner) { }
        int getA() {return owner->a;}
    };
```

But even for this you may have to make some changes, because in versions of C++ before C++11, unlike (again, say) Java, a nested class has no special access to its enclosing class, so it can't see the `protected` member `a`. This will depend on your compiler version. *(Hat-tip to Ken Wayne VanderLinde for pointing out that C++11 has changed this.)*

Comment: type of `a` is `int`. Why do you write `foo *`?

Comment: I'm aware that `a` is of type `int`. I'm not sure what part of my answer confused you in that respect. :-/

Comment: it says `error: invalid conversion from 'foo*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: You should probably note that access rights have changed in C++11. Now the standard reads: "A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member".

Comment: `foo *` means "a pointer to an object of type `foo`". I was assuming that you wanted each instance of `bar` to have an "owner" that's an instance of `foo`; in which case, it needs to have a pointer to that owner. Did I assume wrongly?

Comment: @mahmood: That probably means that you wrote `return owner;` instead of `return owner->a;`.

Answer (score 10):

In C++, nested classes are not connected to any instance of the outer class. If you want `bar` to access non-static members of `foo`, then `bar` needs to have access to an instance of `foo`. Maybe something like:

```
class bar {
  public:
    int getA(foo & f ) {return foo.a;}
};
```

Or maybe

```
class bar {
  private:
    foo & f;

  public:
    bar(foo & g)
    : f(g)
    {
    }

    int getA() { return f.a; }
};
```

In any case, you need to *explicitly* make sure you have access to an instance of `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

The nested class doesn't know about the outer class, and `protected` doesn't help. You'll have to pass some actual reference to objects of the nested class type. You could store a `foo*`, but perhaps a reference to the integer is enough:

```
class Outer
{
    int n;

public:
    class Inner
    {
        int & a;
    public:
        Inner(int & b) : a(b) { }
        int & get() { return a; }
    };

    // ...  for example:

    Inner inn;
    Outer() : inn(n) { }
};
```

Now you can instantiate inner classes like `Inner i(n);` and call `i.get()`.

Comment: @mahmood: `b` is the local argument of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access private member of one class from another. The fact that bar-class is declared within foo-class means that bar in visible only inside foo class, but that is still other class.

And what is p->param?

Actually, it isn't clear what do you want to do

Comment: there is no difference when I make `a` as public

Comment: @mahmood within bar-class *a* doesn't exist at all, it's a part of foo-class. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `p->param` is something that read a value from somewhere else and pass it to `a`. For example, in a file, I wrote '2'. the code reads that and pass to `a`

Comment: @mahmood I asked because your code example isn't full, so maybe that's why what you want to do with your code isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear but there is use case  when you will get this issue .

**Invalid use of non-static data member.**

**When you are using  "non-static data member in another class try to not use with scope resolution operator**
Example::`className::memberData = assignivalue` ;
instead of above try to use object of className class;
Example:: `m_pClassName->memberData=assignValue;`*

Comment: But, what if I'm trying to access a data member that is inherited and hidden by another member (such as a method, or another data member, shadowing the data member I'm trying to access by using the same name) ?

Comment: that also you can try using Class->MemberFunction->member(whatever)