# Using variables from within parent class

Tags: c++, class

I have this structure of classes:

```
class A {
  class B;
  class C;
  int updates = 0;  // invalid use of non-static data member 'A::updates'
  C* example;
  class B {
   public:
    // ...
    void up_plus() {
      updates++;  // problem here is too
    }
    // And some other methods.......
  };
  class C : public B {
   public:
    int size;
    // ...
    void sizeup() {
      example->size++;  // invalid use of non-static data member 'A::header'
    }
    // And some other methods....
  };
};
```

My question is, how can I fix this structure? In Java this will work, but here there is a problem.

Comment: Don't you want B to inherit from A ? Or updates to be a static member of A ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590265/invalid-use-of-non-static-data-member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax;

```
class A {
    int updates = 0; // allowed in C++11 and above
// ...
```

Is allowed with compiling for the C++11 standard and above. Assuming you are using clang or g++, add `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` to the command line.

Secondly, nested classes do not have immediate access to an instance of the outer class. They still need to be constructed with a pointer or reference to the "parent". Given the inheritance relationship of `B` and `C`, the following could be suitable for you;

```
  class B {
   protected:
    A* parent_;
   public:
    B(A* parent) : parent_(parent) {}
    void up_plus() {
      parent_->updates++; // addition of parent_
    }
  };
  class C : public B {
   public:
    int size;
    void sizeup() {
      parent_->example->size++; // addition of parent_
    }
  };
```

[Working sample here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09ad4fa04533a3e2).